# SQL Database Update V12 (preview) -Bacpac?

Tags: windows, azure-sql-database

The export feature of the Sql azure is disabled on the management portal for the update 12. what are my options to regularly refresh my lower environments from production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available now. Please check and respond back if you do not see it.